# Rebase all branches without switching to them

Tags: git, cron, rebase, git-rebase

I would like a cronjob to run every night which does `git fetch` then rebases every branch onto whatever it is tracking. If it doesn't apply cleanly then just abort and try the next one.

This mostly works for that:

```bash
git branch --no-color --no-track | \
sed 's/[ *]*//' | \
grep -v master | \
xargs -I % sh -c '
    git checkout %;
    git rebase;
    git rebase --abort;
    git reset --hard;
    git clean -f;
    git clean -fdx'
```

Now, I want this to NOT affect my current state so that I can not be worried about the state of my git repo when I go home for the day.

Comment: I think there's an answer floating around Stack Overflow to the effect of "you can't rebase without checking out a working copy, in order to resolve merge conflicts."

Comment: Worse case, maybe a stash and a re-apply? I'm a bit scared of that though...

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing this sort of automatic rebasing in a cron job. There's just too many things that could go wrong, and you could easily end up with a mangled repository. Also, if you were to create a local branch to try something out, this auto-rebasing could destroy the history of where that branch came from (even if you only rebase local branches with a tracking upstream branch).

Answer (score 2):

> Now, I want this to NOT affect my current state so that I can not be worried about the state of my git repo when I go home for the day.

Then do it on a local clone of your current local repo.

If it goes well (and Greg points out that it might not), then fetch the updated branches in your local repo from your local rebased clone, and pull/update your current branch on your own term, without having to worry about an automatic process having wreck everything in your working tree.